# Entity framework does not recognize that column is part of primary key

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

I have a two tables in postgresql that look a little bit like this.

```
CREATE TABLE sailor
    id serial NOT NULL,
    boat_id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(256),
    CONSTRAINT sailor_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
    CONSTRAINT boat_id FOREIGN KEY (boat_id)
        REFERENCES boat (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDTE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

CREATE TABLE boat
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name character varying(256),
    CONSTRAINT boat_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

when I generate model from database I get the error "The relationship "boat_id" has columns that are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the relationship. The relationship was excluded".
I am probably missing something obvious, but 'boat (id)' is a primary key. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found that the most probable offender was that the database had a foreign key constraint which had the same name as a primary key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I have this erro message when I was try to update the model from database. The problem was that I had a table with two primary key and I was doing the relationship only with one of this primary key.